# How to Integrate GSA Smartpay Payment with Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, payment-gateway

we need to integrate GSA Smartpay (US) payment method with Magento site.
I have checked default admin configuration and any other extension for integration.

How to integrate this payment method with magento?
Is this possible with Magento configuration?

Any help much appreciation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe these links will give you some ideas how to implement this:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method
http://colourgray.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/magento-create-a-custom-payment-method/

And you could also read comments in **Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract**.

Good luck!